# No repetir numero en un arreglo

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un sistema en C++ en la cual debo almacenar los datos del usuario en un txt. Y debo verificar que no haya duplicación de la papeletas iguales en el array.

Hasta lo momento no he conseguido algún método en c++ que me ayude a evitar duplicación de datos en un arreglo, eso es lo que espero que no se repita ese dato en el txt. Y lo que he conseguido es que se repita. Y hasta a veces que no se guarden.

Pero hasta el momento no he conseguido nada, espero que me ayuden

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;


ofstream archivo;
int noRepetirPapeletas(int arg_vector[], int arg_cont_papeletas);

int main(){

menu();
int opc = 0;
 int  my_vector[20];
 int cont_papeltas = 0;

 do {
      
        if (noRepetirPapeletas(my_vector, cont_papeletas) != 0){
            cont_papeletas++;
        }

        else{
        cout << "Quiere volver a ingresar otro dato? (1 = Si | 0 = No) ";
        cin >> opc;
      }
    } while (opc == 1);


return 0;
}


int noRepetirPapeletas(int arg_vector[], int arg_cont_papeltas) {
     
     int papeletas;
    cout << "Ingrese la cedula: "<<endl;
    cin >> papeletas;
   
   ifstream fichero;
   string linea;


fichero.open("usuario.txt", ios::in);

  while(!fichero.eof()){
  getline(fichero,linea);
    // itero en el vector verificando si la cedula ya fue almacenada
    for (int i = 0; i < arg_cont_papeletas; i++) {

        if (papeletas != arg_vector[i]) {
            archivo<<cedulas<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        // si la cedula ya esta almacenada devuelvo 0
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
  archivo.close();

}

    arg_vector[arg_cont:papeletas] = papeletas;
fichero.close();  
}
```

Comment: En noRepertirCedula, si la cédula  existe retornas un 0 y si no existe no retornas nada ¿Asumes que no retorna 0? Porque no le porque no le pones un return 1; después del file.close(); y en qué parte guardas la cédula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es pedir todos los datos **a la vez**

```
cout << "ingresa el nombre del cliente:\n";
cin >> nombre;
cout << "ingresa el apellido del cliente:\n";
cin >> apellido;
cout << "ingresa el numero de telefono del cliente:\n";
cin >> telefono;
cout << "ingresa la cedula:\n";
cin >> cedula;
```

Después compruebas si la cedula ya existe:

```
std::set<int> cedulas_registradas;
auto [_, nueva] = cedulas_registradas.insert(cedula);
if (nueva)
{  
    // La cedula no está repetida, añadimos la información al archivo
}
```

Y ya finalmente reemplazas el comentario por el código que almacena los datos en el archivo

Comment: mucha gracias por tu comentario

Answer (score 0):

Usa el contenedor [std::set](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), que en resumen, no permite que existen dos o más valores iguales dentro del mismo.

Comment: muchas gracia por tu comentario